# Finding Angular2 class source code

Tags: angular

I'm in the process of learning Angular2 and am having issues finding where imported classes are located.

For example, in my code I would have `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';`

Now, when I go to the `core.d.ts` file, there are a bunch of `*` exports and nowhere is there explicitly a `Component` class exported. I know that if i go through all those files, somewhere there will be an `export class Component`. Obviously that is not ideal, but I'm guessing I'm missing some easier way to find the source code for the `Component` class.

Comment: I'd suggest [API Reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/). Most of the classes are composed from several bits a pieces from all over the place. There's line at the bottom of every object in docs that can be a good starting poing - for example `exported from @angular/core/index defined in @angular/core/src/metadata.ts (line 76)` for the Component...

Comment: thanks @Sasxa that will be useful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a tool such as VS Code, you can right-click on the `Component` word within the import statement and select `Go to Definition`. That takes you directly to the source code.

And note that the import you have is no longer correct as of Angular 2 RC 1. The import is now @angular/core.

Comment: The same result can be obtained by use `F12` or `ctrl+left click` :)

Comment: thank you. This also worked in Atom editor (which is what I'm using).

Answer (score 0):

`.d.ts` is a `TypeScript` type definition file.

Corresponding source file (`js`-version) can be found in the same folder.
However, you won't get sources of Angular 2 with `npm install`.

Better check GitHub https://github.com/angular/angular/find/master. 
You'll find everything there (probably, except for `angular/core`).