# Quickest way to find the source of Component?

Tags: angular

I would like to read the source code of Component or of any class or interface of Angular 2. In the core/src directory there are a lot of subdirectories; is there a quick and rational way to find it?

Comment: Are you talking about the internal Angular2 components? Then see API doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

Comment: Thanks Martin, but it's the documentation, not the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular2 is open source so in it's github repository you could find all angular implementation:
https://github.com/angular/angular

**Updates**

To know exactly where every class or method is exported look at the bottom of angular.io page there's a link to the repository definition and implementation.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I knew it, but how to find a particular code, for example the file which contains the Component decorator?

Comment: In the bottom of each document page there's a link where the specific class is exported from angular repository. So you could start there and walk over the API until find what you want. Or just search in the github search box inside the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your update. It's a good way to find the source code.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Angular2 provides "index" modules to gather sub-modules into single big ones (they reexport them). I'll start by having a look at them so you'll be able to see from which sub-modules they come from.

Here is a sample:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
```

First have a look at `modules/@angular/core/index.ts`. Since `Injectable` is related to dependency injection, `./src/di` should match:

```
export * from './src/metadata';
export * from './src/util';
export * from './src/di'; // <----
export {createPlatform, assertPlatform, disposePlatform, getPlatform, coreBootstrap, coreLoadAndBootstrap, createNgZone, PlatformRef, ApplicationRef, enableProdMode, lockRunMode, isDevMode} from './src/application_ref';
export {APP_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, PACKAGE_ROOT_URL, PLATFORM_INITIALIZER} from './src/application_tokens';
```

You can then have a look at `modules/@angular/core/src/di.ts`. Since `Injectable` is a decorator, `./di/decorators` should match:

```
export {HostMetadata, InjectMetadata, InjectableMetadata, OptionalMetadata, SelfMetadata, SkipSelfMetadata} from './di/metadata';

export * from './di/decorators'; // <------

export {forwardRef, resolveForwardRef, ForwardRefFn} from './di/forward_ref';

export {Injector} from './di/injector';
export {ReflectiveInjector} from './di/reflective_injector';
export {Binding, ProviderBuilder, bind, Provider, provide} from './di/provider';
export {ResolvedReflectiveBinding, ResolvedReflectiveFactory, ResolvedReflectiveProvider} from './di/reflective_provider';
export {ReflectiveKey} from './di/reflective_key';
export {NoProviderError, AbstractProviderError, CyclicDependencyError, InstantiationError, InvalidProviderError, NoAnnotationError, OutOfBoundsError} from './di/reflective_exceptions';
export {OpaqueToken} from './di/opaque_token';
```

So you can now have a look at the `modules/@angular/core/src/di/decorators.ts` file and you will see the corresponding decorator.

```
export var Injectable: InjectableMetadataFactory =
<InjectableMetadataFactory>makeDecorator(InjectableMetadata);
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry. No easier way to find the source code? Compared to Java source code (I am new with Angular), it's a little complicated. Even with your explanations, I have difficulties to find what I am looking for, but it's perhaps because I have not enough experience with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JetBrains' web IDE "WebStorm," you can just `ctrl + click` on a component class name and it will take you to the declaration. This makes for quick navigation from one component to another.

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Thanks. After your answer, I have just got WebStorm. Do you have a good link to know how to write an Angular2 project with WebStorm (which type of project to choose) ?

Comment: A lot of the Angular2 tutorials at [link](https://egghead.io/technologies/angular2) use webstorm, and I've enjoyed their simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found an answer in a related post : [Finding Angular2 class source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754826/finding-angular2-class-source-code?rq=1) I haven't found before asking my question :

> I'd suggest API Reference. Most of the classes are composed from several bits a pieces from all over the place. There's line at the bottom of every object in docs that can be a good starting poing - for example exported from @angular/core/index defined in @angular/core/src/metadata.ts (line 76) for the Component...

I think it's the quickest way to find the file which contains a class. Perhaps Martin thought of this but I haven't noticed the bottom line in the page of the documentation, that gives the file which exports the declaration.